# Windows junction invalid on network share

Tags: windows, networking, symbolic-link, cifs, junction

I usually have this setup on my Windows machines: I share a single folder such as `C:\share` as network share. Then I use `mklink /J somedir C:\somedir` to create junction points to directories I want to access and it works: I can access everything.

Now I have a single computer that has problems: I can access the immediate contents of the share, for example `\\localhost\share\somedir` would work and I can see files and directories. But if I try to go one level deeper I get this error message:

> Share_Path> is not accessable. You might not have permissions to use this network resource. Contact the Administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. The data present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.

The same message is outlined in this [knowledge base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/974103). But this is for Windows Vista and I use Windows 10; on other computers with Windows 10 it works. Also, the scenario is a bit different: The article states that older systems/protocols are used, which is not the case, since all computers use Windows 10.

Is there some kind of strange group policy that was accidentally set on this computer or some other kind of settings that causes this problem?

Comment: Everything was "regular": Only "Users" had access and my user was my regular account that can get admin access. There were no other restrictions.
So what did I do? I created another share, but on another drive. This one worked with seemingly the same settings. I do not know why to this day. On other computers, it works as well.
There has to be some detail I am missing or this is an extremely odd bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to setup a directory junction on my Windows 7 desktop to a directory on a network share.

I was able to get it to work after first creating a directory junction to the share root when logged in as a Local Administrator:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>cd \

C:\>net use I: \\computername\sharename /PERSISTENT:YES
The command completed successfully.

C:\>mkdir \net

C:\>mklink /J net\sharename I:\
Junction created for net\sharename <<===>> I:\
```

Once this has been setup by a Local Administrator, my ordinary User login was able to create further directory junctions to deeper directories within the share:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\gb96>cd \

C:\>mklink /J net\dir1 net\sharename\dir1
Junction created for net\dir1 <<===>> net\sharename\dir1

C:\>mklink /J net\dir2 net\dir1\dir2
Junction created for net\dir2 <<===>> net\dir1\dir2
```